# Getting the attributes of integers and floats

Tags: python

I was playing with the Python interpreter (Python 3.2.3) and tried the following:

```
>>> dir(1)
```

This gave me all the attributes and methods of the int object. Next I tried:

```
>>> 1.__class__
```

However this threw an exception:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
1.__class__
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I tried out the same with a float I got what I expected:

```
>>> 2.0.__class__
<class 'float'>
```

Why do `int` and `float` literals behave differently?

Comment: This question has more and better answers than the question you have marked it a duplicate of. I don't know what purpose it serves other than you being pedantic here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's probably a consequence of the parsing algorithm used. A simple mental model is that the tokenizer attempts to match **all** the token patterns there are, and recognizes the **longest** match it finds. On a lower-level, the tokenizer works character-by-character, and makes a decision based only on the current state and input character – there shouldn't be any backtracking or re-reading of input.

After joining patterns with common prefixes – in this case, the pattern for `int` literals and the integral part of the pattern of `float` literals – what happens in the tokenizer is that it:

1. Reads the `1`, and enters the state that indicates *"reading either a `float` or an `int` literal"*
2. Reads the `.`, and enters the state *"reading a `float` literal"*
3. Reads the `_`, which can not be part of a `float` literal. The parser emits `1.` as a `float` literal token.
4. Carries on parsing starting with the `_`, and eventually emits `__class__` as an identifier token.

> **Aside:** This tokenizing approach is also the reason why common languages have the syntax restrictions they have. E.g. identifiers
>   contain letters, digits, and underscores, but cannot start with a
>   digit. If that was allowed, `123abc` could be intended as either an
>   identifier, or the integer `123` followed by the identifier `abc`.
>
> A lex-like tokenizer would recognize this as the former since it leads
>   to the longest single token, but nobody likes having to keep details
>   like this in their head when trying to read code. Or when trying to
>   write and debug the tokenizer for that matter.

---

The parser then tries to process the token stream:

```
<FloatLiteral: '1.'> <Identifier: '__class__'>
```

In Python, a *literal* directly followed by an *identifier* – without an *operator* between the tokens – makes no sense, so the parser bails. This also means that the reason why Python would complain about `123abc` being invalid syntax isn't the tokenizer error "the character `a` isn't valid in an integer literal", but the parser error "the identifier `abc` cannot directly follow the integer literal `123`"

---

The reason why the tokenizer can't recognize the `1` as an `int` literal is that the character that makes it **leave** the *`float`-or-`int`* state determines what it just read. If it's `.`, it was the start of a `float` literal, which might continue afterwards. If it's something else, it was a complete `int` literal token.

It's not possible for the tokenizer to "go back" and re-read the previous input as something else. In fact, the tokenizer is at too low a level to care about what an "attribute access" is and handle such ambiguities.

---

Now, your second example is valid because the tokenizer knows a `float` literal can only have one `.` in it. More precisely: the first `.` makes it transition from the *`float`-or-`int`* state to the *`float`* state. In this state, it only expects digits (or an `E` for scientific/engineering notation, a `j` for complex numbers…) to continue the the `float` literal. The first character that's not a digit etc. (i.e. the `.`) is definitely no longer part of the `float` literal and the tokenizer can emit the finished token. The token stream for your second example will thus be:

```
<FloatLiteral: '1.'> <Operator: '.'> <Identifier: '__class__'>
```

Which, of course, the parser then recognizes as valid Python. Now we also know enough why the suggested workarounds help. In Python, separating tokens with whitespace is **optional** – unlike, say, in Lisp. Conversely, whitespace **does** separate tokens. (That is, no tokens except `string` literals may contain whitespace, it's merely skipped between tokens.) So the code:

```
1 .__class__
```

is always tokenized as

```
<IntLiteral: '1'> <Operator: '.'> <Identifier: '__class__'>
```

And since a closing parenthesis cannot appear in an `int` literal, this:

```
(1).__class__
```

gets read as this:

```
<Operator: '('> <IntLiteral: '1'> <Operator: ')'> <Operator: '.'> <Identifier: '__class__'>
```

---

The above implies that, amusingly, the following is also valid:

```
1..__class__ # => <type 'float'>
```

The decimal part of a `float` literal is optional, and the second `.` read will make the preceding input be recognized as one.

Comment: Thanks for the most comprehensive explanation. Exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Could this be considered a bug in the interpreter?

Comment: @AJMansfield: No. It could, however, be considered a feature request. I believe Ruby handles attribute access on number literals nicely, probably because there's much more reason to want to do such a thing in Ruby. In the meantime, you can use `1 .whatever` or `(1).whatever` if you need it.

Comment: @AJMansfield Not really. Making the parser simpler and avoiding potential sources of language ambiguity at the cost of developer friendliness is a perfectly valid design decision. (An advantage would be, to wit, that having flunked my compiler class I can still adequately explain how it works.)

Comment: Admittedly handwaving a bit, I believe Python uses a separate tokenizer and parser step, and different parts of what leads to the error happen in each. I'll see if I can make this less of a lie-to-children.

Comment: @ajay Inspired by the comments, I have now substantially rewritten the answer to more accurately reflect what's actually going on. (The general gist of the original version remains, but I was making some leaps in my explanation and conflating some compiler construction concepts.)

Comment: @AJMansfield It's not a bug *because* Python allows `1.` as a float value (or NUMBER).  See http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/grammar.html (the lex'ing happens *first*) - it would require a special grammar rule/provision (or a restriction on NUMBER) to allow `1.x` to be equivalent to `1 .x`

Answer (score 27):

It is a tokenization issue... the `.` is parsed as the beginning of the fractional part of a floating point number.

You can use

```
(1).__class__
```

to avoid the problem

Comment: Or put a blank after the `1`:  `1 .__class__`

Answer (score 10):

Because if there's a `.` after a number, python thinks you're creating a float. When it encounters something else that isn't a number, it will throw an error.

However, in a float, python doesn't expect another `.` to be a part of the value, hence the result! It works.  :)

**How do we get the attributes, then?**

You can easily wrap it in parentheses. For example, see this console session:

```
>>> (1).__class__
<type 'int'>
```

Now, Python knows that you're not trying to make a float, but to refer to the int itself.

Bonus: putting a blank space after the number works as well.

```
>>> 1 .__class__
<type 'int'>
```

Also, if you only want to get the `__class__`, `type(1)` will do it for you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Or you can even do this:

```
>>> getattr(1 , '__class__')
<type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parenthesis to surround the number:

```
>>> (1).__class__
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

Otherwise, Python sees the `.` after the number and it tries to interpret the whole thing as a float.